How to configure postfix to allow only specific email ids?
We have a requirement to allow only a specific from email id from a specific IP address using postfix.
Is there a way to do that as I was unable to find any map which would permit only specific emails?

What does "Email id" mean for you? (envelope sender email address, Message-ID:, …)
